# Jenkins Master Horizontal Scaling

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to horizontally scale Jenkins? We have a requirement where we can more number of jobs will be added and built every day. I understand we can distribute jobs to slaves and master should be only used for orchestrating. However, masters memory is also limited and we cant keep adding jobs, since master will have to maintain job details, history etc.

What if we have some 10000+ jobs running in parallel daily? Will we be able to scale Jenkins master?

Comment: You could scale the master vertically, i.e. add more resources to the master to accommodate additional cpu and memory. You could also split Jenkins into smaller functional pieces.

Comment: You could also split Jenkins into smaller functional pieces. -> How do we do this? Are you mentioning jobs to be split or the whole jenkins to be split here?